# What is the best way to create a FxCop custom code analysis rule that uses Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, roslyn, fxcop

I was tasked with creating a code analysis rule that can catch swallowed exceptions. All was working well until I tested my rule with async methods and the rule as unable to detect the swallowed exceptions.

I decided to give Roslyn a try. For Roslyn to work, I needed to know the location of the source file, and I was able to get that from the property `member.SourceContext.FileName`. Problem is, that property isn't always there. I noticed that this is always the case for non-public methods.

Is there a reliable way to get the source file using the FxCode code analysis engine? Is there a better way to use roslyn for code analysis?

FxCop rule:

```
internal sealed class DoNotSwallowExceptionsRule : BaseFxCopRule
{
    public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
    {
         Method method = member as Method;
         if (method != null && method.Body != null && method.Instructions != null)
         {
             string sourcefileName = method.SourceContext.FileName; //sometimes is null

             if (sourcefileName != null)
             {
                string source = File.ReadAllText(sourcefileName);

                var result = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);
             }
         }
         return Problems;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create a FxCop rule that uses Roslyn. Create a Roslyn Diagnostic with optional Fix. The process is explained here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Samples-and-Walkthroughs. You can package these as a NuGet package or install them using a vsix.

Comment: @jessehouwing Can this be integrated to a build server? Our build servers only have up to Visual Studio Build Tools 2013 installed. I took a look at the sample and it seems like it will only work as a visual studio extension. I also took a look at the nuget package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.FxCopAnalyzers for a clue on integrating this to a project, and it looks like it will only support Visual Studio 2015. Currently, my custom FxCop rule is integrated in my project and automated build and a developer doesn't need anything special installed to run the rule.

Comment: Requires 2015 build tools.

Comment: Btw Visual Studio 2015 would not be required to run the rules, they can be integarted in the Roslyn version of FxCop. See: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Diagnostics/FxCop That way you can integrate them in older build systems by using the 2015 build tools.

Comment: It seems like this means that developers would have to use Visual Studio 2015 to run the new rules. I was able to accomplish the requirements of the custom rule using IL analysis. I still think Roslyn would be best going forward, I just don't think our current development environment allows us to easily integrate Roslyn.